# I am trying to add all the opportunity amount on quota actual amount field

Tags: salesforce

I need to add all(SUM) the amount from the opportunity of all closed won opportunity which lies between the start and end date of quota.

1. Opportunity should be closed won
2. closed date should be within the start and end date of quota
3. assigned to the user which is a look up field on quota which is equal to
   owner of quota

Below is the code

```
public with sharing class listopponquota {

public list<Opportunity> oppList{get;set;}

public listopponquota()
{
    String selectedVal ='';
    oppList = new list<Opportunity>();
    oppList();
}




*public pageReference oppList() {
    Id qId = (Id) ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    system.debug('Id-->'+qId);    

    List<Opportunity> oppList1 = new List<Opportunity>();

    oppList1 = [Select Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName,OwnerId,Amount From Opportunity where StageName = 'Closed Won'];

    system.debug('quotaList1-->'+quotaList1);
    if(quotaList1.size() > 0){
        for(quota__c q : quotaList1){

            map<id,double> amtmap = new map<id,double>();
            for(aggregateresult ag : [SELECT SUM(Amount) sum,Quota__c FROM Opportunity where Quota__c in :quotaList1  and StageName = 'Closed Won' group by Quota__c ]){
                amtmap.put((ID)ag.get('Quota__c'), double.valueof(ag.get('SUM')));
                {

                    amtmap.put((ID)ag.get('Quota__c'), double.valueof(ag.get('SUM')));
                }
                list<Quota__c>Qtalist = new list<Quota__c>();

                for(id iid : QtaIds){
                    Quota__c quot = new Quota__c(id=iid); 
                    if(amtmap.containskey(iid)){
                       q.Actual_Amount__c = amtmap.get(iid);
                    }else{
                         q.Actual_Amount__c = 0;
                    } 
                    Qtalist.add(quot);       
                } 
                if(Qtalist.size()>0){
                    update Qtalist;
                    return null;
                }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}*
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue may be that you are not defining `quotaList1`. You should also probably pull that SOQL query out of the for loop. Grab all the records you need prior to entering the loop.

A quick modification to your SOQL query:

`[SELECT SUM(Amount) sum,Quota__c FROM Opportunity where Quota__c in :quotaList1  and IsWon = true group AND CloseDate >= Quota__r.StartDate__c AND CloseDate <= Quota__r.EndDate__c AND Quota__r.OwnerId =: System.UserInfo.getUserId() by Quota__r.Name ]`

Most importantly though, how do the objects relate? Are the opportunities children of the `Quota__c` object, or is there also a field on the `Quota__c` defining the opp it is tied to?